# How to associate multiple values with enums in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, enums, swift3

I'm trying to use an enum to categorize the various sections in a `UITableView`.

Here's the current implementation of the **Section** `enum` :

```
enum Section: Int, CustomStringConvertible {

    case open = 0
    case closed = 1

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .open:
            return "Open"
        case .closed:
            return "Closed"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm using it to name the titles for the headers in my `UITableView` sections :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return Section(rawValue: section)?.description
}
```

I'm just curious to know if there's a better way of implementing this. Perhaps with tuples. I'm not exactly sure, but I'd love to see if there's a better solution.

This is just one use case and the two cases given are just for brevity. I'd like to use multiple values, for instance `UIColors` associated with the given `case`.

Comment: If that's the only thing you're using this enum for, I don't see the purpose of the enum at all.

Comment: @matt This is a smaller use case. In the real app, I'm using many more values, not just open and closed. Plus, I'd like to reuse the same for other view controllers. Anyway, my question was more about if the enum is structured correctly or not.

Comment: Then please ask your real question. I can't read your mind. What I see in your world depends on what you show me. :)

Comment: @matt That's true, I should've phrased it better in the original question. Again, I'm kind of tossed by the usage of `enum` in Swift especially when it comes to multiple values.

Comment: However, I don't see what "many more values" has to do with anything; I think my answer applies very well if there are dozens of values. If you have integers from 0 to n and each one corresponds to a string, that's an array of strings.

Comment: Well, as I've said in my comments and my answer, it seems to me your enum is a red herring. You've foxed yourself by using the wrong data structure.

Comment: My answer stays the same. Now you've got an array of strings and an array of colors. If you wanted to be cool you could, I suppose, have an array of some StringAndColor struct. But turning a whole number into a thingy is an array of thingy where the whole number is the index.

Comment: @matt Alright, I guess I got some reading to do. `Enums` are frustrating for me. Never know when to use them.

Comment: Might like to read my book on that topic: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_why_enums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is set up a correspondence between numbers and strings:

```
0 -> Open
1 -> Closed
```

... then it's hard to see what the enum is for. What you want is a *dictionary* where the numbers are keys, or even just a simple *array*:

```
let arr = ["Open", "Closed"]
```

In the array, the string is indexed by the numbers:

```
return arr[rawValue: section]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the enum to provide other information for the header (eg. background color, or whatever) you could add more vars to the enum as you did with the description.

But if you are only using for header titles you are probably better with an array:

```
let sectionTitles = ["Open", "Closed"] //var if the section can change.

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sectionTitles[section]
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that's not copied from the answer I already gave.

Comment: We were typing at the same time dude, chill out.

Comment: @AntonioAnchondo upvoted to counter that guy's hyper-aggressive downvoting of any answers that aren't his.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will be adding more variables or functionality to this enum, your syntax is fine. You can consolidate a bit when naming the cases like this:

```
case open, closed, thirdCase, fourthCase
```

If your enum has a rawValue of Int, and the cases start from 0 and number incrementally, you don't have to assign the values.

If you wanted the increments to start at a different number than 0, you can set it up like so:

```
case open = 3, closed, thirdCase, fourthCase
```

Your cases would then have a rawValues of 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: How does that get him to the string "Open"?

Comment: the same way he is currently getting them. I'm just helping him with the case naming syntax, not meaning to remove the CustomStringConvertible and its description variable. He can access it the same way he is now.